# Change framerate in GStreamer pipeline twice

Tags: gstreamer

I have problem with making pipeline in GStreamer.

My pipeline  looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=200/1 ! videorate max-rate=50 ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=500000 byte-stream=true ! h264parse ! rtph264pay mtu=1400 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=false async=true
```

At this point, I am optimalizing pipeline for application. So instead of `videotestsrc` in pipeline, there will be `appsrc`, which gets frames from application, which returns frames. Everytime `appsrc` asks for frame, application would return one. Camera have about 50 FPS.

I'll help explanation with a picture:

[image]

Gray line means time. Let's say camera send frame every 20ms (50 FPS) (red dots) and `appsrc` asks every 20ms, but asks allways 1ms before camera produces new frame (blue dots). This will generate delay of 19 ms, which I am trying to get low as possible.

My idea is to use `videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=200/1`, to let source ask for new frame every 5 ms, which implies the blue dot will be 4 times faster, than camera getting new frames, which mean 4 frames will be equal. After getting those "newest" frames, I want to (**without encoding**) to limit framerate back to 50 FPS using `videorate max-rate=50`.

Problem is, my pipeline doesn't work in application; not even as terminal command `gst-launch-1.0`.

How can I control framerate twice in one pipeline? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `set_property` to set/modify properties of your element. The element handle can be obtained using `[gst_element_factory_make][1]`.

```
rate = gst_element_factory_make("videorate","vrate")
g_object_set("rate","property-name","property-value")
```

You can set/modify the values based on your requirements when the pipeline is playing.